# Java, ICS calendar format not showing time when imported in Outlook or Thunderbird

Tags: java, time, outlook, icalendar, rfc5545

I am working on a Java project in which I am creating an ICS file and there is something wrong with date and time. Whenever I import the ICS file, I want to show the startTime of event and endTime of Event in the ICS file.

I tried using the constructor which contains endTime as well, no luck, still shows 00:00. The below code I am using to generate an ICS file and below that is the content of the ICS file.

Code :

```
 Calendar icsCalendar = new Calendar();
            icsCalendar.getProperties().add(Version.VERSION_2_0);
            icsCalendar.getProperties().add(CalScale.GREGORIAN);

            String startDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss'Z'").format(groupNotes.getStartTimestamp());
            String endDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss'Z'").format(groupNotes.getEndTimestamp());
            net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Date startDt = null;
            net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Date endDateFortuna = null;
            try {
                startDt = new net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Date(startDateString, "yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss'Z'");
                endDateFortuna = new net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Date(endDateString, "yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss'Z'");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            java.util.Calendar endDate = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
            endDate.setTimeInMillis(groupNotes.getEndTimestamp().getTime());
           /* long difference = groupNotes.getEndTimestamp().getTime() - groupNotes.getStartTimestamp().getTime();
            int min = (int) (difference / (1000 * 60));
            Dur dur = new Dur(0, 0, min, 0);*/
            VEvent vEvent = new VEvent(startDt, endDateFortuna, groupNotes.getMnotetag());
            vEvent.getProperties().add(new Description());
            try {
                vEvent.getProperties().getProperty(Property.DESCRIPTION).setValue(groupNotes.getMnotetext());
                vEvent.getProperties().add(new Organizer("MAILTO:" + groupNotes.getNoteCreatorEmail()));

            } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException | ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            icsCalendar.getComponents().add(vEvent);

            FileOutputStream fout = null;

            try {
                fout = new FileOutputStream(calFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            CalendarOutputter outputter = new CalendarOutputter();
            outputter.setValidating(false);

            try {
                outputter.output(icsCalendar, fout);
                return new FileInputStream("mycalendar.ics");
            } catch (IOException | ValidationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Here is how my ICS file looks like :

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20150910T152828Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20150911
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20150911
SUMMARY:
DESCRIPTION:poip
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:email@gmail.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Now when I import this, no time is mentioned in Outlook, thunderbird or Evolution. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are only specifying a `DATE` and not a `DATE-TIME` for the `DTSTART` and `DTEND` properties of your `VEVENT`.

Note: those are short for Date-Time Start and Date-Time End).

for more details you can refer to RFC5545 and specifically [DATE-TIME](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5), or [DTSTART](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.2.4), and [VEVENT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.1).

The second one, also will remind you that the default for `DTSTART` is to use `DATE-TIME` format and not `DATE` format.

The third one indicates usage for `DTSTART` with only `DATE` value

> The "VEVENT" is also the calendar component used to specify an
> anniversary or daily reminder within a calendar.  These events
> have a DATE value type for the "DTSTART" property instead of the
> default value type of DATE-TIME.