# Java: ics not read in outlook

Tags: java, email, outlook, calendar

I have written java code to send calendar invite. It works good with gmail, thunderbird. The clients read the ics and show the invitation properly.

But the same mail doesn't seem to be working on Microsoft Outlook. Outlook doesn't recognize the mail as calendar invite and hence no accept, reject buttons are shown.

Following is the code snippet used:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.addHeaderLine("method=REQUEST");
message.addHeaderLine("charset=UTF-8");
message.addHeaderLine("component=VEVENT"); 

BodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
textBodyPart.setContent("Invitation for an event.", "text/plain");

BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");
messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
messageBodyPart.setContent(inviteMessage, "text/calendar");

Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
multipart.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
message.setContent(multipart);
```

The ics file that I'm sending is:

`BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:1.0
PRODID:-//Michael Angstadt//biweekly 0.6.0//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20170123T115919Z
ORGANIZER:mailto:x@y.com
UID:12345678
COMMENT:Event Invitation
DTSTART:20170123T120319Z
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Event Invitation
DURATION:PT30M
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;ROLE=CHAIR;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=XY:mail
 to:x.y@gmail.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR`

Found similar problems on stackoverflow, tried the mentioned solutions but nothing helped.
[Multipart email with text and calendar: Outlook doesn't recognize ics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523861/multipart-email-with-text-and-calendar-outlook-doesnt-recognize-ics)

[Sending Outlook meeting requests without Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461889/sending-outlook-meeting-requests-without-outlook?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Java, ICS calendar format not showing time when imported in Outlook or Thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506065/java-ics-calendar-format-not-showing-time-when-imported-in-outlook-or-thunderbi)

Comment: Have you tried to export an original Outlook-invitation to ICS and checked its attributes?

Comment: Yes, did that too. Didn't work. Also manually created an event with google calendar and sent invitation to email configured on outlook. Outlook could recognize that invitation so hardcoded the gmail ics in code and tried but that too didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying content type as below did trick for me.

```
messageBodyPart.setContent(inviteMessage, "text/calendar;method=REQUEST");
```